# _commit issue with fd()

Tags: c++, io, flush

In researching forcing files to be written as quickly as possible, I have seen the following chunk of code in a few places:

```
_commit(outputFile.rdbuf()->fd());
```

where outputFile is an std::ofstream object. I am basically doing the following:

```
std::ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.write((char*)blocks, sizeof(blocks));
outputFile.flush();
_commit(outputFile.fd());
outputFile.close();
```

blocks is a simply an array of char arrays. What I am doing is writing to an array of char arrays to represent the contents of a binary file, then pushing that array out to the file itself. I need the files to get written as quickly as possible as the medium is somewhat less reliable flash memory and the chance of power outages is unusually high.

When I attempt to compile, I receive the following error on the `_commit` line of code:

```
error C2039: 'fd' : is not a member of 'basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >'
```

How should I go about getting the file descriptor of outputFile and passing it to _commit?

EDIT: I have changed the above code to reflect using ofstream.fd(), which is supposed to be a public member of [ofstream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277406%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: One glance at `basic_filebuf` class confirms that it doesn't have `fd()` member, so somebody is using non=standard extensions.

Comment: I guess I should amend my question to simply ask for a way to get the file descriptor for outputFile and pass it to _commit.

Comment: No such thing in standard C++, neither there is a `_commit` function. Non-standard extensions are by definition compiler dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone should have written this as an answer. They have not so I will steal their glory. :-)

The file descriptor is implementation dependent. Some systems might not have one. So the C++ Standard does not define any method to get it from a `fstream` or `filebuf`.

The `_commit` function in your example is definitely implementation dependent. One big hint is that the name starts with an underscore. A bit of Google shows that `_commit` only works on Windows.

To get what you want, you could write your own class derived from `streambuf`. This customized class would implement IO in the low-level terms that you want to use (Windows, POSIX) and can provide extra functions to return file descriptors or flush data to disk.

To use the custom class as a stream you would create a `ostream` and pass it a pointer to your `streambuf` class.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am confused by something else: MSDN shows that fd() is a member of ofstream, and it shows up in Intellisense. However, the _commit line throws the error that fd is not a member of basic_ostream. It seems to me that this is a VS non-standard extension that should server this purpose. I'm confused as to why I apparently can't use fd() at all.